# Unexpected email - x-newtrunsreceiver header

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, exchange-server, office365

Struggling to find any useful information on this, so I'm hoping some light may be shed here.

I received an email to which I don't appear to have been addressed.

It's a legitimate email to our organisation, however there appears to be no reason for it to be delivered to me. Digging through the headers DOES reveal my email address, in a header field x-newtrunsreceiver.

ie.

x-sender: sender@sendersemail
x-newtrunsreceiver: legitimaterecipient1@ourorg
x-newtrunsreceiver: myemail@ourorg
x-newtrunsreceiver: legitimaterecipient2@ourorg

The recipients legitimaterecipient1 and legitimaterecipient2 are in the To: and Cc: fields respectively.

I am kind of assuming I've been BCc'd, but can't find any info on what the x-newtrunsreceiver header field is / does.

Any help welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

MIME headers have absolutely nothing to do with who actually receives the message.

When a message is submitted to an SMTP server, the recipients are specified in the "RCPT TO" SMTP command. The MIME headers that follow the DATA command can contain anything. The SMTP server can in theory take a look at the To and CC headers, but there is absolutely no requirement or reason to do that.

Now the receiving SMTP server can add an extra header (e.g. Apparently-To), but, again, it has no obligation to do that.

Comment: Thanks, but can you shed any light on the specific MIME header referenced in the OP? Can't find anything!

Comment: I have never seen it, sorry.